# To find range of sin(2{x}) where {} denotes the fractional part of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question is To find range of sin(2{x}) where {} denotes the fractional part of function

Now 2{x} $\in$ [0,2). so by drawing sin graph range should be [0,1]-{sin(2)}. is this right? thanks

Comment: I guess, you mean $\{x\}$ is the fractional part and not the integer part? How do you treat negative $x$?

Comment: The range is $[0,1]$, what do you mean by $-\{\sin(2)\}$?

Comment: $\{0\}=0$ but $2\{\pi/4\}=2\pi/4$ and $\{\}$ is never negative so $\sin(0)\leq\sin(2\{x\})\leq\sin(2\pi/4)$ cool?

Comment: Still open: $\{-2/3\}\approx -0.333$ or $\{-2/3\}\approx +0.667?$. And 
$\{\sin(2)\}\approx0.909$

Comment: @Jam because it is open at 2

Comment: @gammatester Yeah, you're right. I've always assumed $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ but I guess that's not given.

Comment: @Jam Is not this always true?

Comment: @J.Deff You might have been using $\{\}$ in a weird way that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is assuming fractional part of $x$ is always positive.

The graph will have a period of 1. As you have noticed. For the domain $2\{x\}\in[0,2)$. However $\frac{\pi}{2}\in[0,2)$ so the curve will reach its maximum before the next period starts. As such the range will be $[0,1]$.

[image]